# ReferenceError: user is not defined in user api

Tags: sails.js

When I open `localhost:1337/user` I got Internal Server Error
Something isn't right here.

> ReferenceError: user is not defined

How can I fix it? My API is not working. I can't insert data in database using html forms in sailsjs.
My user model is:

```
    module.exports = {
    attribute: {
 firstname: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true
  },
  lastname: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true
},
 organisationName: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true
},
 DepatmentName: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true
},
 DOB: {
    type: 'date',
    unique: true
},
 DOJ: {
    type: 'date',
},
 DOL: {
    type: 'date',
},
 Address: {
    type: 'string',
},
 City: {
    type: 'string',
},
 State: {
    type: 'string',
},
 Country: {
    type: 'string',
},
  email: {
    type: 'string',
    email: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true
    },
    encryptedPassword: {
        type: 'string',
    },
    ContactNumber: {
        type: 'integer',
    },
    //toJSON: function() {
//      var obj = this.toObject();
//
//  }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a variable "user" and it doesn't exist or it's empty. Check youre code for this variable..

In youre usermodel, you only have firstname and lastname. I guess you need one of this. If you want more specific help, then you have to show us some extra coding of the page, not only the model.

Comment: now api is not working properly. when i typed this:   http://localhost:1337/user/create?name=aaaaaa then i got {
  "id": 2
} i can't see name

Comment: show us what your controller do. because there is high probability the problem caused by the way you call user in your controller.

Comment: sole.info("Program Started");

module.exports = {
 'new': function (req, res) {
   res.view();
 },

 operations: function(req,res,next){ 
  var params = req.body;

          //create a user
          User.find(params, function(err, createdData) {
              if(err){
                 res.badRequest({
                     error: err
                  });
               } else {
                 return res.json({
                           status: "success",
                            data : createdData
                 });
            }

        });

      }
  }

Comment: I suspect that your req.body contains different format, so when you use User.find using params from req.body, sails return ReferenceError

Comment: please tell me the basic controller code for inserting data in mysql database using forms.